# how to access a certain value from a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having this kind of structure in an array of objects how do i access the underlined data? [image]

Comment: Show your effort please?

Comment: Here's the answer anyway `obj["Gokul"]["comments"][0]["A"]`, assuming `obj` refers to the root of the tree.

Comment: thank youu. what if i want to print the A itself ?